# CSS3 radial-gradient edge color does not match final color stop all around

Tags: css, gradient

Given the following HTML:

```html
<body><div class="container"></div></body>
```

and CSS:

```css
body {
  background-color: #e9f9e9;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 100, color-stop(0%, #fcfffc), color-stop(100%, #e9f9e9));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#fcfffc, #e9f9e9);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(#fcfffc, #e9f9e9);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(#fcfffc, #e9f9e9);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(#fcfffc, #e9f9e9);
  background: radial-gradient(#fcfffc, #e9f9e9);
}
```

The edges of the radial gradient do not match the final color stop, and thus does not match the containing element's background color (which is the same as the gradient's final color stop), causing an abrupt color change at the edge of the `<div>`. How can this be avoided?

Screenshot with adjusted contrast & saturation to make the problem obvious: [image: Screenshot with adjusted contrast & saturation to make the problem obvious]

View live on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amarshall/FZAJM/). Verified to occur on OS X 10.7 in Chrome 14 & 16, Safari 5.1, Firefox 7 & 9a2; Windows 7 in Chrome 14 & 16, Firefox 7 & 9.0a2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because, according [the specs](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#radial-gradients) the default value for the `size` argument of the radial gradient function is a `cover`, so the circle positioned so that it tries to cover all the square area with pixels that have alpha > 0.

So, to fix it, set this argument to `contain`: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/FZAJM/1/ — and it would be fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Did not know about the `contain` option, and somehow missed it when going over the docs. Also, apparently `contain` is a synonym for `closest-side`.

Comment: For me, "contain" is an invalid property ... but your mentioned "closest-side" works like intended, thanks very much!